# Trello suspend notifications to all members

Tags: trello, notifications

Is it possible to suspend all notifications to board members for a short time.  We have decided to change the way we set up Trello and I need to do a whole load of changes to exiting cards.  I would like to suspend notifications whilst I make these wholesale changes or I will bombard everyone with messages.

Answer (score -3):

Would it be possible for you to unsubscribe the members from the board?
I think they only get notifications if they are @ mentioned, or if they have subscribed to a particular card (or list, or the whole board)

Comment: I was asking if the original poster would, in their situation, be able to unsubscribe members

Comment: Then that's a comment on their question, and still not an answer. Please only use the Answer space to offer a solution to the original question. To leave comments on other people's questions, you need to wait until you get to 50 reputation points. [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/21960)